# Altering the size of math mode while using (incompatible) xymtex package

Tags: math-mode, chemfig, resize, relsize, xymtex

I have to use variable sized math mode and also use some chemical figures. For chemical figures, I usually use `chemfig` package. However in some case using `xymtexpdf` is easier. The problem is, resized math mode doesn't **always** work with xymtex.

The MWE here explains all-

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{relsize,graphicx}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf} % uncommenting this line produces the expected output

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Stars}
    
    This should be a normal sized star = $\star$
    
    This should be a smaller sized star = $\mathsmaller{\star}$
    
    This should be a yet smaller sized star = $\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{\star}}$
    
    This should be a normal sized star, displaystyle = ${\displaystyle \star}$
    
    This should be a normal sized star, textstyle = ${\textstyle \star}$
    
    This should be a smaller sized star, alternate way = ${\scriptstyle \star}$
    
    This should be a yet smaller sized star, alternate way = ${\scriptscriptstyle \star}$
    
    This should guarantee to produce a smaller size star = \scalebox{0.8}{$\star$}
    
    This should guarantee to produce a yet smaller star = \scalebox{0.65}{$\star$}
    
    
    \textbf{Equations}
    
    This should be a normal sized equation = $x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}$
    
    This should be a smaller sized equation = $\mathsmaller{x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}}$
    
    This should be a yet smaller sized equation = $\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}}}$
    
    This should be a normal sized equation, displaystyle = ${\displaystyle x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}}$
    
    This should be a normal sized equation, textstyle = ${\textstyle x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}}$
    
    This should be a smaller sized equation, alternate way = ${\scriptstyle x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}}$
    
    This should be a yet smaller sized equation, alternate way = ${\scriptscriptstyle x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}}$
    
    This should guarantee to produce a smaller size equation = \scalebox{0.8}{$x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}$}
    
    This should guarantee to produce a yet smaller equation = \scalebox{0.65}{$x^2+56+\sin x+\sqrt{x}$}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to rectify it?

[image]

Comment: The package `xymtex` just loads a lot of other packages. By binary search I could find out that the culprit is the `chemist` package, which in fact redefines `\star` (and some other symbols). However, I have no time to work out a solution right now, hence only a comment.

Comment: It's worse than I thought: try a very simple $a_{\Gamma}$. `chemist` redefines a lot of symbols putting them into an `\hbox` thus destroying TeX's math style handling.

Comment: Hmmm ... for now, I am making do with ``\scalebox{0.65}{$\star$}`` type directives. I guess, that is the price I have to pay for using ``xymtex``. I dont have to scale mathematical symbols very often but using ``scalebox`` everytime is a nuisance as well as probably a cause of slowness.